# Rails - Refactoring controller method to Application Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just getting into Rails and I'm having some trouble understanding some syntax elements that the guides I'm reading just seem to take for granted.

This afternoon I was working on a small sample project and was trying to refactor some code.  Basically, I want to include links to admin only controls in my nav bar that are dependent on which page is currently being viewed.  This was my original code:

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :admin_controlls

  def new
  end

  def create
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def index
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
    def admin_controlls
      @adminControlls = "rooms"
    end
end
```

My thinking was that this code would essentially be the same in every controller where I want to create admin controls.  The only difference being the value of the flag variable @adminControlls I want to pass to the View.

So, I attempted this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper

  def admin_controlls(page)
      @adminControlls = page
  end
end
```

And changed the Rooms controller to this:

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter admin_controlls "rooms"

  def new
  end

  def create
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def index
  end

  def destroy
  end

end
```

I think my confusion starts with the before_filter and why calling a method there requires a symbol.  I can't figure out how to pass a string into the method when it is called as a symbol, and all my efforts to change the before filter to call a method (as above) have failed.  Overall I'm just not feeling like I'm grasping some subtleties of the syntax.  If anyone has a resource that would be helpful, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Have you looked at `params[:controller]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this: `before_filter { |c| c.admin_controlls "rooms" }` ? A similar question could be found here: [How can I send a parameter to a before filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675579/how-can-i-send-a-parameter-to-a-before-filter)

Comment: That sure does work.  As does a simpler before_filter { admin_controlls "rooms" } or before_filter do admin_controlls "rooms" end

I'd sure love if someone could explain why this block syntax is necessary though.  I'm really having a hard time understanding the syntax.  I feel more like I'm memorizing a list of "do this, not thats" rather then understanding why certain things are required.

Comment: You'll get used to it. It's part and parcel of learning a new language/framework. It helps to look at the source though: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb. You'll see that it requires a block as its second argument. The docs might provide a better insight: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-_insert_callbacks

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it needs a symbol is that the call to "before_filter" gets run when the Controller class is first loaded... but you want the actual before_filter *method* (admin_controlls) to be called on every single action (not just the once).

So the load-time before_filter call stores the name of the method to call later... on every time that the controller action is run.