# Rails 4 before_action, pass parameters to invoked method

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
class SupportsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_support, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  ....
```

Is it possible to pass a string to the method `set_support` to be applied for all 4 view methods?
Is it possible to pass a different string to the method `set_support` for each method in the view?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

```
before_action only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
  set_support("value")
end
```

Comment: Combining @tihom and this response you can get something like this

`before_action only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] do |c|
  c.set_support(params[:action)
end`

Comment: I suggest one string like: before_action { |action| action.update_user_balance(10000) }, where update_user_balance it's a model method which get params: def update_user_balance(arg) ... end

Comment: This works well with longer methods, otherwise I would use the answer submitted by Kyle Decot below.

Answer (score 63):

You can use a lambda:

```
class SupportsController < ApplicationController
  before_action -> { set_support("value") }, 
    only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  ...
```

Answer (score 13):

A short and one-liner answer (which I personally prefer for *callbacks*) is:

```
before_action except:[:index, :show] { method :param1, :param2 }
```

Another example:

```
after_filter only:[:destroy, :kerplode] { method2_namey_name(p1, p2) }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can pass a lambda to the `before_action` and pass `params[:action]` to the `set_support` method like this:

```
class SupportsController < ApplicationController
  before_action only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] {|c| c.set_support params[:action]}
  ....
```

Then the param being sent is one of the strings: `'show'`, `'edit'`, `'update'` or `'destroy'`.

Comment: I tried to get this syntax to work, but was unable to. The syntax Kyle used worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The SupportsController

```
class SupportsController < ApplicationController    
  before_action only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] { |ctrl|
    ctrl.set_support("the_value")
  }
...
```

The ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController
  def set_support (value = "")
    p value
  end
...
```