# Upgrading Ruby breaks before filters in Rails (Devise, Pundit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running a Rails app that after upgrading the Ruby version to 2.5.1 and also 2.6.0 stopped working. I noticed that it has something to do with passing a block in controller's callbacks:

```
prepend_before_filter only: [:create, :destroy] { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }
```

fails with an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end
...ter only: [:create, :destroy] { request.env["devise.skip_tim
```

My setup is:

```
devise (4.6.1)
rails 5.0.7
ruby 2.5.1
pundit 2.0.1
```

I upgraded Ruby version I was using to 2.6.0 and had a problem, then went down to 2.5.1 and the problem still persisted

I also found these twho threads that seem to talk about a similar problem: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4703
[Rails 4 before_action, pass parameters to invoked method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260288/rails-4-before-action-pass-parameters-to-invoked-method)

I updated Devis and Pundit, but without any luck :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest replacing `prepend_before_filter` which was deprecated with `prepend_before_action` and using parentheses

```
 prepend_before_action(only: [:create, :destroy]) { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }
```

or using the `do ... end` block syntax

```
prepend_before_action only: [:create, :destroy] do 
  request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true
end
```

Comment: thank you. That was it. Do you happen to know what broke this? Ruby version?

Answer (score 0):

For me works adding parentheses ():

```
prepend_before_filter(only: [:create, :destroy]) { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }
```